# Print matching lines from two files containing columns of numbers

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have been to trying to do the following:

- I have a file with 3 columns of numbers and been wanting to print the matching rows when compared to a smaller file with one column of numbers.
- I'm using `grep -F` but it always gives me rows that don't match.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking this kind of question, please be sure to include a minimal representative example (i.e. example input along with desired output) so that contributors can understand the task and verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers. Also don't forget to describe details such as file format, column delimiters, content type and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're seeing things like matching `101` when your smaller file has `10` in it.  This is because 10 is a substring of 101.

If your main file only had one field, you could use grep's `-x` option for exact matches.  e.g.

```
grep -x -F -f smallerfile.txt mainfile.txt
```

Because it has three fields, you have to match each of them individualy, so you'd have to use something like perl or awk.  e.g., with awk:

```
$ cat smallerfile.txt 
1
10
25
152

$ cat mainfile.txt 
1 2 3
5 10 15
10 11 12
100 101 102
150 151 152
250 255 260

$ awk 'FNR == NR { nums[$1]++ ; next }
       $1 in nums || $2 in nums || $3 in nums' smallerfile.txt mainfile.txt
1 2 3
5 10 15
10 11 12
150 151 152
```

BTW, this would get tedious to write or update the script if you had to check more than three fields.  To avoid that, you could write an awk function that iterates over each field (no matter how many there are) and check if the values of any of them are in the `nums` array.  e.g.

```
$ awk 'function check_all_fields() {
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
           if ($i in nums) return 1
         }
         return 0
       }
       FNR == NR { nums[$1]++ ; next }
       check_all_fields()' smallerfile.txt mainfile.txt
1 2 3
5 10 15
10 11 12
150 151 152
```

As you can see, the output is identical to the first version.

The `check_all_fields()` functions returns a 1 (true) as soon as it sees a matching field in an input line.  If it never sees one in the current line, it returns 0 (false).

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked!

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using the following approach wherein we make use of `sed` to guide `grep` in searching the strings taking into account their neighborhood:

```
sed -e 's/.*/\\<&\\>/' f1 | grep -Ef - f3col
```

Outputs:-

```
1 2 3
5 10 15
10 11 12
150 151 152
```

---

Using `awk` we can do as shown. We first form an associative array `a[...]` keyed on the columns of the single-column file .After that , on every line of the three-column file, we initialize the flag `p` and increment it whenever there is a data from single column file matching any of the fields. Then at the end of the for loop, we conditionally print the reCord if the flag was ever incremented at least once.

```
awk '
NR==FNR{a[$1];next}
{
  for (p=i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i in a) p++
}p>1
' f1 f3col
```

---

`python` natively supports the `set` data structure we do as follos where the printing happens when the intersection of the sets is nonempty:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
file1,file2 = sys.argv[1:]

with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
  s1 = { _.rstrip() for _ in f1 }
  for _ in f2:
    s2 = set(_.rstrip().split())
    if bool(s2 & s1):
      print(_,end="")
' f1 f3col
```

---

Using `POSIX sed` constructs we first generate POSIX sed code using the single column file n apply that to the three-column file:

```
sed -e '
  h;G;G
  s/.*/^&$/
  s|\n| /b&/ |g
  s|.*|/&/b|;$a\
d
' f1 | sed -f - f3col
```

---

`perl` can do this multiple ways:

```
perl -lane '
  @A || chomp(@A=<STDIN>);
  for my $f (@F) {
    print,last if grep { $f == $_ } @A;
  }
' f3col < f1
```

---

```
perl -MList::Util=any -lane '
  chomp(@A=<STDIN>) if !@A;
  print if 
    any {
      my $f = $_;
      any { $_ == $f } @A;
    } @F;
' f3col < f1
```